# UnitTest method that performs Volley network call

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-volley

My android (kotlin) app performs a network call to a backend API using Volley library.

I am writing some unit tests and I already tested the call emulating the network call using a json file read but now I would like to test the complete flow with all the network stack involved and really calling the backend server (I have a stub backend which always returns the same response).

Is it possible to implement this with a UnitTest and not using and androidTest?

When I try to execute the unit test I currently receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/StatusLine
```

At the following line:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, OkHttpStack(mClient, sslSocketFactory))
```

I suppose the issue is because in UnitTest I don't have a complete context but I am mocking it using

```
@Mock
private lateinit var mockContext: Context
```

But I don't know how to mock it properly to have it working for volley library.

Is it possible to write a UnitTest testing all the flow like this? 
If yes, how?

Thank you!

Manuela.